# Saving a file consisting of two layers

Tags: gdal, kml, geopandas, fiona, pandas

I have a geopandas dataframes (A) and (B). I wanted to save them into disk using a same file but with two different layers.

I knew to save one dataframe as follows:

```
A.to_file('out.kml', layer='A', driver='KML')
```

How can I save dataframe B into same file using layer 'B'?

Comment: `B.to_file('out.kml', layer='B', driver='KML')`?

Comment: it cannot write over the existing file, out.kml. it throws error

Comment: Then use file format which for which fiona supports layers. Like GPKG.

Comment: gdal/ogr supports layer on kml and i really need kml file this time. Is not there some tricks on fiona's schema or keywords to be inserted into .tofile...?